# Round double down to nearest multiple of other double in Java?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, math

I realize this isn't that great of a title, so I'll try to explain more thoroughly.

Basically, I have a double that changes only by small amounts, known as `clusterSize`. Then, I have a second double, a latitude or longitude on a map, known as `coord`. I want to round `coord` down to its nearest value that would be divisible by `clusterSize`, but we haven't found any easy way to do so.

Code tried:

```java
private double roundDown(double coord, double clusterSize) {
    return clusterSize * Math.floor(coord / clusterSize);
}
```

And:

```java
private double roundDown(double coord, double clusterSize) {
    return Math.floor((coord + clusterSize/2) / clusterSize) * clusterSize;
}
```

Neither of which produced the results that I was looking for. If you could point me to a library or function that could easily accomplish this task, that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Does it give unexpected values for all coords or is it just negative values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, here's what you're looking for:

```
private double roundDown(double coord, double clusterSize) {
    return coord - (coord % clusterSize);
}
```

Explanation:

Mod operator (`a%b`) returns the remainder of a divided by b. By substracting the remainder we're guaranteeing divisibility.

Test runs:

```
coord clusterSize => result
1.1   .2          => 1.0
1.12  .11         => 1.1
```

Note: remember to properly process situations where `coord < clusterSize`

Comment: Makes perfect sense once I saw that function, simple and elegant. Thank you so much.